# Where do I use getWindowManager() within Live Wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I'm getting the error "The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type LiveWallpaperService"

Since I'm creating an activity there is no way to reference that, how would I go around getting the screen width and height before the main class initialized within onCreateEngine()

It's the first thing that's called. Before I was using background image for dimensions but that's proving a pain with different screen sizes.

Can anyone please help me here? I've tried:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
```

With no luck.

Also tried:

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

I get the error: "Activity cannot be resolved to a type"

Also:

```
((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
```

with : "WindowManager cannot be resolved to a type"

What ever I try, where ever I place this code I always get the same error, I tried using the

```
onSurfaceChanged
```

Int with width and height but they initialize too late and my application crashes, can anyone help my here thanks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mContext = getBaseContext();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
mScreenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
mSreenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```